#  Jquery ValidationEngine Custom Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have two fields. I want to have first field to be more than zero(0) and the second field to be more than one(1). Also the first field should never be equal to or greater than the second field.

this is what i have done so far

```
$("#entryForm").validationEngine();

$('#field1').rules('add', {
    min: 1,
    messages: {
        required: 'Some custom message for the required field'
    }
});

$('#field2').rules('add', {
    min: 2,
    messages: {
        required: 'Some custom message for the required field'
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to add the rules without modifying the jquery.validationEngine-en.js file

Comment: please find the code in the question itself. it's being edited now

Comment: $("#field1").rules is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

required: 'Some custom message for the required field'

Comment: There are lot of examples are given here for usage of validationengine,.js https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: yeah i have gone through it but never found the comparison sort of thingy

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this:

```
<input value="field1" class="validate[required,equals[field2]] text-input" type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
```

Or You can write a separate function call do the validations there as well.All these mentioned here:

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html